# how to make dynamically created field as mandatory field in jquery

Tags: jquery

I had created this field dynamically and i couldnt make it as mandatory field.
Could you please suggest where am I doing wrong.

```
var mail = '<label for="title" class="col-xs-12" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" ></span >Additionals</label>' +
        '<div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form " id="additionalmail" type="email" required /></div>' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info class="col-xs-6" onclick="remove(' + intTextBox + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ></span > Remove </button >';
```

---

corrected error with double class on button

```
var mail = '
    <label for="title" class="col-xs-12" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span >Additionals
    </label>' + '
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form" id="additionalmail" type="email" required />
    </div>' + '
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-xs-6" onclick="remove(' + intTextBox + ')">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ></span > Remove 
    </button >
';
```

Comment: var mail = '<label for="title" class="col-xs-12" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" ></span >Additionals</label>' +
   '<div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form " id="additionalmail" type="email" required /></div>' +
   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info class="col-xs-6" onclick="remove(' + intTextBox + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ></span > Remove </button >';

Comment: Please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it in a comment (which is unreadable).

Comment: no idea why its hiding the data. I pasted in the question itself. but its not taking tried to edit either.No luck. Thats the reason I had added in comments section

Comment: @dev: indent your code by 4 spaces... It formats itself in the question.

Comment: So you have a `var` containing a long string representing elements to append to document. Do you append it actually?

Comment: yes i could see the field in form.But form getting submitted  by keeping this field as blank also

Comment: You have a double class on button declaration class="btn btn-info class="col-xs-6" it must be: class="btn btn-info col-xs-6"

Comment: So... The additional email input that you add... With the attribut `required`... And what? It does not do the required effect?

Comment: @sigma... Nice catch... But I do not think it matters in OP issue... While not being sure.. ;)

Comment: When is that input appended? Is it BEFORE the submit click? Is there a validation plugin used? Is it inside a valid `<form>` element? ... And finally... Any error in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
   $("#mydiv").append('<label for="title" class="col-xs-12" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" ></span >Additionals</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form " id="additionalmail" type="email" required /></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-xs-6" onclick="remove(\' + intTextBox + \')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ></span > Remove </button >');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<button id="btn1">TEST APPEND</button>
```

Here is a working append, you dont need to concatenate divs just the onclick but must backslash the single quotes.
Hope it helps, happy codding

Comment: OP question is about how to make it `required`... It does not work for some reason... The appends does not seems to be a problem as he stated *«yes i could see the field in form.But form getting submitted by keeping this field as blank also»*

Comment: At this point OP should post all the code including the submit, the code he posted on the mail var is erroneus, dont gives any error on console but just dont execute, or the OP can use the version i suggest and let him tell if it works or not :)

Comment: I agree... ok then ;)

Comment: Im calling this adding of a new field with a button when i click add button in my code. Even though there was no issue with append i tried this way, this also created a field but my remove function is not working.  and more over still the field is not changed to mandatory                                             function remove(id) {

    if (intTextBox != 0) {

  $("#gen" + id).remove();
    }
}

Comment: Guys could some one please suggest me how to make a dynamically created field   as mandatory

Comment: Please can you post the entire code you are using, just the code you posted here seems is not enough. Normally the input field with attribute required must work 100% but may be there is something else causing the problem. Just in case try to use required="required" instead of using just required. Thanks.

Comment: I had posted entire code in answers. Because of the total number of lines .Could you please go through the entire code and let me know where am I doing wrong. My extra email field is not turning as mandatory and validate statements are not working

Answer (score 0):

### Schema.json

```
{
    "title": "Form",
    "description": "info",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {     

        "mailAddress": {
            "title": "mail Address",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

### Options.json

```
{
    "fields": {         

        "mailAddress": {
            "label": "mail Address",
            "order": "11",
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

### View.json

```
{
    "parent": "bootstrap-create",
    "displayReadonly": true,
    "layout": {
        "template": "./HTML/UI/Template.html",
                    "bindings": {

                        "mailAddress": "#mailAddressLayout"

                    }
    }
}
```

### Template.html

```
<div class="container">

    <legend class="alpaca-container-label">

        <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="" style="cursor: pointer;">Form</span>

    </legend>

    <div class="row" id="mailAddressLayoutParent">
        <div class="col-xs-6" id="mailAddressLayout"></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addField()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Extra mail
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

### code.js

```
var intTextBox = 0;
var target = "Content";

function addField() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
        var contentID = $('#mailAddressLayoutParent');
        var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newTBDiv.setAttribute('id', 'fdname' + intTextBox);
        newTBDiv.setAttribute('class', 'row');      

        var mailbox = '<label for="title" class="col-xs-12" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" ></span >Extra mail Address</label>' +
        '<div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form-control " id="Mail1" type="email" required /></div>' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info class="col-xs-6" onclick="removeField(' + intTextBox + ')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ></span > Remove mail </button >';
        newTBDiv.innerHTML = mailbox;
        contentID.after(newTBDiv);      

    });
}

function removeField(id) {

    if (intTextBox != 0) {

        $("#fdname" + id).remove();
    }
}

$(function () {

    $("#divNodeTabContent").alpaca({

        "schemaSource": "/json/UI/Schema.json",
        "optionsSource": "/json/UI/Options.json",
        "viewSource": "/json/UI/View.json",
        "options": {
            "fields": {                  



                "Mail1": {
                    "validator": function (callback) {

                        var value = this.getValue();
                        //var re = /^\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
                        var re = new RegExp(/^\w+([-+.'][^\s]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/);

                        if (re.test(value)) {

                            callback({
                                "status": true
                            });
                        } else {
                            callback({
                                "status": false,
                                "message": "Invalid Email Address"
                            });
                        }

                    }

                }

            },
            "form": {
                "buttons": {
                    "validate": {
                        "styles": "btn",
                        "title": "Submit",
                        "click": function () {
                            this.refreshValidationState(true);
                            if (this.isValid(true)) {

                                toastr.info("validations of the form looks good.", "Success");
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   

        }        


    });

});
```

Comment: Hello again @Dev. I try to replicate this on my pc but still you are not showing the entire code. The jSon files are correct as structured, you dont include the libraries you are using so i use the standart jQuery and bootstrap but still i miss some information. $("#divNodeTabContent").alpaca({ what is this??? because i get alpaca is not a function and another question, i miss the submit button that is defined inside alpaca so when i execute i just get the add Extra mail and Remove but not the submit. Please include all the full code so i can check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks lot Sigma. "$("#divNodeTabContent").alpaca"  'divNodeTabContent' is the form where i'm working on and im creating the fields using alpacajs and validations are written in jquery.  From the 'form-> buttons-> 'submit' button will get create.